# Does QGIS support .sld style files for raster layers?

Tags: qgis, raster, sld

I'm currently looking at the documentation for geoserver, and I'm trying to load a raster and .sld file in QGIS to see if I can edit .sld files for raster layers. The .sld and raster are located here: http://docs.geoserver.org/2.4.1/user/styling/sld-cookbook/rasters.html

Unfortunately I'm unable to load the .sld file in QGIS 2.2. I am only allowed to load .qml files when I try to load a style for that layer. It appears that QGIS only loads .sld files for vector layers.

Is there anyway to use an .sld file on a raster layer?

Comment: Having the same issue - research is showing that the answer may be "no, it doesn't" - I'll let you know if I find anything

Answer (score 7):

There is a plugin in the Official Repository that seems to be what you were looking for. It's called SLD4raster.

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SLD4raster/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but gives an error when trying to export as qml